# Capture requests from steam game

Tags: python, steam

Is there any way to capture packets from steam game and use them to send requests (via python)?
i'd like to write a bot usign requests, and wonder is there any way to do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for a sniffing tool. Read about **packet sniffing**.

For Python, you may use [python-libpcap](https://pypi.org/project/libpcap/).

Comment: more looking for something like wireshark, just before encryption, and caputure only the given application/game